# What are the rules for talking over the table during poker games?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In "Best of Both Worlds," Data, Commander Shelby, Riker, Wes, Deanna, and Geordi are playing poker. Wesley asks Data if he has "another king in the hole."

Data then chastises Wesley for asking an inappropriate question.

Seconds later, Geordi tells the group that Riker has a straight flush and Data immediately breaks in to inform Wesley that the commander may be bluffing!

Seriously? Is there a rule that says that pitiful ensigns can't talk over the table, but commanders can?

Of course, Wesley doesn't chastise Geordi or Data for being a hypocrite. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 10):

It's not to do with rank but rather the etiquette of playing poker. Wesley has asked another player directly about his hand, and that player has declined to engage with him about it.

Geordi has speculated that Riker has a straight flush, based on what he strongly thinks Riker has, and other players are commenting on what he thinks.